# Git Branch not being detected when trying to switch to it on staging server

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have created a git branch from master at a certain commit that is a bit behind. I made some updates and tried to push to that specific branch.

Steps I did:

```
git clone [url]
git checkout -b [new-branch] [commit-hash]
git add .  / . git commit -m "message"  /  git push origin [new-branch]
```

After push I get the following error:

```
remote:

remote: Create pull request for [new-branch]:

remote:   http://stash......[url]

remote:
```

When I try to checkout to my new branch of the staging server I get:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/[new-branch]': unknown revision or
>   path not in the working tree.

Odd thing is that the branch appears in Atlassian Stash, also the commits appear.

Comment: The "error" that you get is an informational message, it's not an error. Have you *pulled from the remote repository* on your staging server?

Comment: Is your Bitbucket server same as staging server?

Comment: I have tried "Creating remote branches" from https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches from this page, and create a remote repository but I don't quite understand how that works. Do i need to pull from remote repo ?

Comment: First you need to pull from remote repository

Comment: And how do I do that ? And what exactly does this remote repo work ?